# Autocompletar código con doble TAB

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

No me funciona autocompletar al dar doble TAB después de una palabra clave como `for`, `foreach`, etc.

Al darle doble TAB después de `foreach` debería aparecer algo así:

```
foreach (ítem in Articulos) 
{
    ;
}
```

Comment: Hola Mario, deberías agregar la versión de Visual Studio que estás usando, pues puede variar dependiendo de la versión.

Comment: Toda informacion que puedas aportar es buena, siempre que sea relevante

Comment: En Herramientas-->Opciones-->Editor de Texto-->C#-->Intellisense. Revisa las opciones en ese apartado.

Comment: Lo que hice fue bajarme el nuevo instalador y me lo actualizó a la última versión 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 y ahora ya lo hago perfectamente. Gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Con dar un sólo TAB debería funcionarte si tienes activados el "Auto-completar" en el apartado de Funciones-Palabras-Ambos.
Busca en la barra de herramientas esa opción de "Autocompletar".

Quedaría algo así:

```
for (var i = Things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  
    Things[i]  
}
```

Comment: Lo que hice fue bajarme el nuevo instalador y me lo actualizó a la última versión 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 y ahora ya lo hago perfectamente. Gracias !